# EFM - Epub for Monocle is not working in IE

Tags: javascript

Could you solve my question please

EFM - Epub for Monocle  is not working in IE but working in other browser.

I download form https://github.com/rschroll/efm/tree/gh-pages

error like Unable to get property 'getData' of undefined or null reference

So can you please suggest me how to read .epub file using EFM - Epub for Monocle.It is very imaportant for me

Best Regards,

Yogendra

Comment: For starters: what version of IE are you using? which ones fail? BTW, Monocle does not list IE among the browsers it supports: https://github.com/joseph/monocle#browser-support

Comment: IE 7 to IE 11 nothing is working.